# Python 3 and Boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

How to make python script result to become a variable. Ans use that variable into a value of another python script. I want to insert the result "ImageId" and insert in the " client.create_launch_template"

For example:

```html
import boto3
from dateutil import parser

def newest_image(list_of_images):
    latest = None

    for image in list_of_images:
        if not latest:
            latest = image
            continue

        if parser.parse(image["CreationDate"]) > parser.parse(latest["CreationDate"]):
            latest = image

    return latest

client = boto3.client("ec2", region_name="ap-southeast-1")

filters = [
    {"Name": "description", "Values": ["poc ami"]},
    {"Name": "owner-id", "Values": ["144970827735"]},
    {"Name": "state", "Values": ["available"]},
]

response = client.describe_images(Filters=filters)
source_image = newest_image(response["Images"])
print(source_image['ImageId'])

response = client.create_launch_template(
    DryRun=False,
    ClientToken='string',
    LaunchTemplateName='string',
    VersionDescription='string',
    LaunchTemplateData={
        'KernelId': 'string',
        'EbsOptimized': True|False,
        'IamInstanceProfile': {
            'Arn': 'string',
            'Name': 'string'
        },
        'BlockDeviceMappings': [
            {
                'DeviceName': 'string',
                'VirtualName': 'string',
                'Ebs': {
                    'Encrypted': True|False,
                    'DeleteOnTermination': True|False,
                    'Iops': 123,
                    'KmsKeyId': 'string',
                    'SnapshotId': 'string',
                    'VolumeSize': 123,
                    'VolumeType': 'standard'|'io1'|'gp2'|'sc1'|'st1'
                },
                'NoDevice': 'string'
            },
        ],
        'NetworkInterfaces': [
            {
                'AssociatePublicIpAddress': True|False,
                'DeleteOnTermination': True|False,
                'Description': 'string',
                'DeviceIndex': 123,
                'Groups': [
                    'string',
                ],
                'InterfaceType': 'string',
                'Ipv6AddressCount': 123,
                'Ipv6Addresses': [
                    {
                        'Ipv6Address': 'string'
                    },
                ],
                'NetworkInterfaceId': 'string',
                'PrivateIpAddress': 'string',
                'PrivateIpAddresses': [
                    {
                        'Primary': True|False,
                        'PrivateIpAddress': 'string'
                    },
                ],
                'SecondaryPrivateIpAddressCount': 123,
                'SubnetId': 'string'
            },
        ],
        'ImageId': '**ImageId**',  ### I need to paste here the result
        'InstanceType': '**InstanceType**', ### I need to paste here the result
        'KeyName': 'string',
        'Monitoring': {
            'Enabled': True|False
        },
        'Placement': {
            'AvailabilityZone': 'string',
            'Affinity': 'string',
            'GroupName': 'string',
            'HostId': 'string',
            'Tenancy': 'default'|'dedicated'|'host',
            'SpreadDomain': 'string'
        },
        'RamDiskId': 'string',
        'DisableApiTermination': True|False,
        'InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior': 'stop'|'terminate',
        'UserData': 'string',
        'TagSpecifications': [
            {
                'ResourceType': 'client-vpn-endpoint'|'customer-gateway'|'dedicated-host'|'dhcp-options'|'elastic-ip'|'fleet'|'fpga-image'|'host-reservation'|'image'|'instance'|'internet-gateway'|'launch-template'|'natgateway'|'network-acl'|'network-interface'|'reserved-instances'|'route-table'|'security-group'|'snapshot'|'spot-instances-request'|'subnet'|'traffic-mirror-filter'|'traffic-mirror-session'|'traffic-mirror-target'|'transit-gateway'|'transit-gateway-attachment'|'transit-gateway-route-table'|'volume'|'vpc'|'vpc-peering-connection'|'vpn-connection'|'vpn-gateway',
                'Tags': [
                    {
                        'Key': 'string',
                        'Value': 'string'
                    },
                ]
            },
        ],
        'ElasticGpuSpecifications': [
            {
                'Type': 'string'
            },
        ],
        'ElasticInferenceAccelerators': [
            {
                'Type': 'string'
            },
        ],
        'SecurityGroupIds': [
            'string',
        ],
        'SecurityGroups': [
            'string',
        ],
        'InstanceMarketOptions': {
            'MarketType': 'spot',
            'SpotOptions': {
                'MaxPrice': '',
                'SpotInstanceType': 'persistent',
                'BlockDurationMinutes': 123,
                'ValidUntil': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
                'InstanceInterruptionBehavior': 'stop'
            }
        },
        'CreditSpecification': {
            'CpuCredits': 'string'
        },
        'CpuOptions': {
            'CoreCount': 123,
            'ThreadsPerCore': 123
        },
        'CapacityReservationSpecification': {
            'CapacityReservationPreference': 'open'|'none',
            'CapacityReservationTarget': {
                'CapacityReservationId': 'string'
            }
        },
        'LicenseSpecifications': [
            {
                'LicenseConfigurationArn': 'string'
            },
        ],
        'HibernationOptions': {
            'Configured': False
        }
    },
    TagSpecifications=[
        {
            'ResourceType': 'client-vpn-endpoint'|'customer-gateway'|'dedicated-host'|'dhcp-options'|'elastic-ip'|'fleet'|'fpga-image'|'host-reservation'|'image'|'instance'|'internet-gateway'|'launch-template'|'natgateway'|'network-acl'|'network-interface'|'reserved-instances'|'route-table'|'security-group'|'snapshot'|'spot-instances-request'|'subnet'|'traffic-mirror-filter'|'traffic-mirror-session'|'traffic-mirror-target'|'transit-gateway'|'transit-gateway-attachment'|'transit-gateway-route-table'|'volume'|'vpc'|'vpc-peering-connection'|'vpn-connection'|'vpn-gateway',
            'Tags': [
                {
                    'Key': 'string',
                    'Value': 'string'
                },
            ]
        },
    ]
)
```

So all in all I can get the values of the string but its not clear to me how to use that values to next command.

Comment: I don't understand. you print the result image id. Then just put in to some variable and use it.

Comment: Do you mean "latestImage = print(source_image['ImageId'])".

Comment: If i do this how can I use that variable to used it in JSON string ('ImageId': 'latestImage')